# R-value Reference push_back Function

Tags: c++11, move, encapsulation, rvalue-reference, push-back

I'm writing a Queue class.  I have two versions of push_back for the new C++11 standard.  One of these versions uses a rvalue reference as a parameter.  My version works, but I think it must be lacking something:

```
 97 template <typename T>
 98 void Queue<T>::push( T && val ) 
 99 {
100     c.push_back( val );
101 }
```

It seems I should have used std::move, but I'm not sure how to implement this.  c in the above function refers to a deque object encapsulated in my Queue class.  Any help understanding what I should do to construct this function appropriately would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's so complicated about passing `val` through `std::move`?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible.  So, my call to push_back could be: c.push_back( std::move(val))?

Comment: Yes, and it should be. As an aside, never paste line-numbers. They break copy-paste.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't think there's a universal reference here. The type of T is already deduced in `Queue<T>`.

Comment: @remyabel: You're totally right, I overlooked the `<T>::`.  My bad.  Your answer was 100% right, please undelete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need `std::move` here, but you could also use `emplace_back` here:

```
template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::push( T && val ) 
{
     c.emplace_back( std::move(val) );
}
```